# Type several columns using right-to-left language

Tags: languages, multicol, right-to-left

I want type Farsi (this language is right-to-left) in several columns.
How do I start the contents from the first column to the right?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: So you basically want a version of `multicol` Package ordering the columns right-to-left?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you are saying that you use `bidi` package together with `multicol` package and the order of contents produced by `\tableofcontents` is wrong. Here is an example showing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setRTL
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{First}
\columnbreak
\section{Second}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the PDF output, columns are ordered RTL; however the order in the table of contents is obviously wrong. This is a known bug. This happens because  the delay of the `\write` without `\immediate` writes the entry at page shipout time, when the page number is known.

With `twocolumn` option, this problem does not happen (I should state that the problem existed in earlier versions of `bidi` package) because `bidi` fools TeX and so the order of contents is right; try:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setRTL
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\newpage
\section{Second}
\end{document}
```

I could fix this but unfortunately that is not likely to happen since `bidi` is already in its final version (version 12) and no more development will be done. I am also not sure about a workaround that could possibly fix this.

Comment: How do you mean, 'final' version? Will there be no more development of its API/semantics, ever?

Comment: Without donations to the project, there will be no more development of its API/semantics, ever.

Comment: Where's the donations page? Were you counting on large donors or individual users?

Comment: @einpoklum: There is no donation page. Both large donors and individual users are welcome. If you are interested, then you can send me an email: Vafa.Khalighi@student.uts.edu.au

Comment: With a multicol version 1.8a or above the bug can be easily corrected, see my answer. Of course this only helps for the general audience when 1.8 is on CTAN and not only in the SVN, but I hope this will happen soon.

Answer (score 6):

For two-column mode throughout the document a good approach is given in a different answer (unless you also require balancing).

For more than 2 columns or when balancing of column data is needed the answer *should* be to use the `multicol` package. However, as demonstrated by Vafa Khalighi this results in an incorrect ordering of toc entries.

The reason for this is some incorrect patching of `multicol` done in the file `multicol-xetex-bidi.def`. The an attempt is made to reverse the columns from the default

```
 hbox ( vbox-col-1 rule vbox-col-2 rule ... rule vbox-col-n )
```

To

```
 hbox ( vbox-col-n rule vbox-col-n-1 rule ... rule vbox-col-1 )
```

As logical as this seems it is wrong, because in that case TeX sees `vbox-col-n` first when it does as `\shipout` and this any `\write` from the last column first and thus that will be the order they show up in the ToC.

So the correct way to implement this is more complicated: we needed to make take see `vbox-col-1` even though it is at the right edge of the page. So abstractly the code for this does

```
 hbox ( hskip to right margin
        hskip - columnwidth
        vbox-col-1 
        hskip - columnwidth
        hskip - columnsep            % or even a little more magic for rules
        hskip - columnwidth 
        vbox-col-2  ...  vbox-col-n )
```

some time ago I implemented support for RL typesetting and made exactly the same error :-( and that version is still out on CTAN.

A version with correct RL support is v1.8a or higher which currently can be obtained from the [SVN sources](http://latex-project.org/svnroot/latex2e-public/required/tools/multicol.dtx) (you still then have to unpack it by running `tools.ins`, so it is not that convenient). I hope to change that in the near future as I'm curently making a few other updates to the source.

With that version in place the file `multicol-xetex-bidi.def` can be drastically shortened to just contain the following line:

```
\RLmulticolcolumns
```

which unconditionally reverses the multicol columns (but nothing else). Or one keeps the file completely empty and instead uses that command like `\setRTL` in the document.

And perhaps one also want's to move the footnoterule to the right (which bidi doesn't seem to do, but `xepersian`does so this should be used with care):

```
\renewcommand \footnoterule{%
    \kern-3pt\hbox to\textwidth{\hskip .6\textwidth\hrulefill }%
    \kern2.6pt}
```

With the above changes to undo the patches by bidi (and a new version of multicol) we then get desired output.

The `xepersian` package used in the answer by Vahid Damanafshan internally also uses the `bidi` package so would suffer too from the incorrect patch for `multicols`. But with the suggested change above, we get really nice output (not that I speak the language, but at least I'm able to identify the numbers in the ToC and they come out correctly; and sorry for the footnote being by its own, just wanted to have one to see what happens):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \section{بخش اول}
  \ptext[1-2]\footnote{\ptext[3]}
  \section{بخش اول}
  \ptext[4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

And as a result we get:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly, try the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{ptext} 
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\section{بخش اول}
\ptext[1-3]
\section{بخش دوم}
\ptext[1-3]
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

Comment: Additionally, for more examples and information, you can refer to [the ParsiLatex website.](http://www.parsilatex.com)